# Unhandled Exception at igd10iumd32.dll

Tags: c++, windows, exception, visual-studio-2013

Seems like I'm getting an unhandled exception related to the graphics when working on my project in Visual Studio.
I updated the graphics drivers recently, due to Windows 10. It seems like since then these problems happen. It's not on my code, as I've been on and on changing it trying to fix it for full days with no avail. This is a devastating problem.
I've eventually downgraded my Intel graphics driver in attempt to fix this issue, but nichts.
What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I get:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x657F994A (igd10iumd32.dll) in Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000158.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll just post this as an answer.

I'm having the same issue. I also upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. My laptop has both integrated and dedicated graphics cards, but the preferred graphics card is a NVIDIA GeForce 710m. I thought that I only needed to upgrade my drivers, but after  upgrading my driver from 340.52 to the latest (353.62), my problem still persisted.

Below is a sample 'hello world' program that reproduces the program on my machine. It's seemly random - it may happen in the 2nd loop, or the 279th.

```
#include "sdl/SDL.h"
#include "sdl/SDL_syswm.h"
int main( int argc, char*argv[] )
{
  if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    return 1;

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 4 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE, 0 );

  SDL_Window* sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "tac",
    30, 60,
    1366, 768,
    SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
  if( !sdlWindow )
    return 1;

  SDL_GLContext mainContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext( sdlWindow );
  if( !mainContext )
    return 1;

  while( true )
  {
    SDL_Event mySDLevent;
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &mySDLevent ) )
    {
    }
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow( sdlWindow ); // <-- it crashes here
  }

  SDL_GL_DeleteContext( mainContext );
  SDL_DestroyWindow( sdlWindow );
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

First-chance exception at 0x5ECB9958 (igd10iumd32.dll) in MyGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x77007B85.
Unhandled exception at 0x5ECB9958 (igd10iumd32.dll) in tacMain.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x77007B85.

My callstack comes from these dlls

```
igd10iumd32.dll
nvoglv32.dll
kernel32.dll
ntdll.dll
```

So I assume it's a driver issue?...

Comment: I found igd10iumd32.dll as part of my Intel HD Graphics 4000 graphics card driver (from device manager -> display adapters) under driver details.
http://puu.sh/jpSoH/adba43dcd3.png

However, my intel driver version is already current
http://puu.sh/jpSxI/f6efa7f759.png

But there is hope in a beta driver for windows 10
http://puu.sh/jpSAX/7180c7ff1c.png

Comment: Exactly my case. And I really really appreciate your answer. Somehow, it started working by itself. I started to switch back and forward the drivers, and then it worked, after a long time waiting by doing nothing. Like, the screen gone black, then gone back to normal, and it started working again. Quite weird, but I had to roll back to an older version of the drivers. And yes, it's an Intel graphics driver's problem for sure. Not sure if you have it solved for you. Have you?

Comment: While switching the drivers (and even replacing Intel's with Microsoft's Basic Graphic Drives), it seemed like it started overclocking its processing in the game. It was crazy, specially if I didn't have the framerate lock. I temporarily disabled it, and it gone fast like mad. I thought I was using a super computer or something, and I'm not even exaggerating. Regardless, all seems to be fine now, somehow.

Comment: I don't know how to find the Microsoft Basic Display Driver. I made a post on the Intel forum ( https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1834334 ), and they linked me to a driver that didn't support my gpu (Intel HD 4200, not HD 4000 ), so I'm still looking for ways to solve my problem.

Comment: To find the Microsoft basic display adapter, you go to the Device Manager in your computer, and go to display drivers or whatever it is called. There you can select Intel HD 4200 Graphics (?) and go to properties and change it to something else, like microsoft's.